# Is any personal or sensitive data collected as part of the Smart Scopes Server?

Tags: application-development, scopes

The Smart Scopes technology implies submitting search queries online for them to be processed by the Smart Scopes Server from Canonical.

Is any personal or sensitive data collected as part of the Smart Scopes Server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is no.

Thes Smart Scopes Server collects aggregated statistics related to search queries and doesn’t collect any data to identify any user. Only the search query is stored on the server.

Users are not tracked in any way: there isn't a notion of anyone’s search history and queries and feedback cannot be correlated to a user. As a consequence, Smart Scopes search results are not personalized. If collecting anonymous search queries is still a concern, any scope or entire communication with Smart Scopes Server can be easily disabled via the user’s Privacy Settings dialog.

If a scope requires personal information to work (such as account information) then it will only be able to run on the client but never on the server.

The Smart Scopes spec contains [information about all the data that is sent to the server](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SmartScopes1304Spec#Data_and_metrics_passed_to_the_Smart_Scopes_service).