# Smart Scopes run-order

Tags: unity-dash, scopes, smartscopes

Using Smart Scopes on my desktop Ubuntu 13.10, I noticed that sometimes (typically the first time I search for something using Dash) applications installed on my system take a backstage to online recommendations (shopping, for sure, but also my online files etc.). That is, I'd type in the name of an application, and for some reason online suggestions would appear first; not until after several seconds have passed do I get the obvious suggestion: the app itself.

Following @WarrenHill's very good answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/363951), I'm able to disable the online scope and see that it shouldn't really take this long for application-suggestions to come up. Hence, this isn't some FIFO architecture (which I'd be fine with; as long as there aren't any local results, I don't mind seeing online suggestions); having the online scopes enabled actually *slows down* getting the result I want.

However, that doesn't mean I'd never like to get online suggestions. In fact, I kind of like them; they're just much less useful to my everyday work than local results. So, my question is:

> Is there any way of specifying run-order for scopes? Can I stop Dash from seeking online suggestions until after all local results were gathered?

Answer (score 2):

have a look at this answer [How to change the order of scopes in a lens?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129822/how-to-change-the-order-of-scopes-in-a-lens)

from what I understand, the scopes actually *do* display the results first in first out

As for my personal experience, I have smart scopes disabled in the first place. Yet typing a search term takes quite some time to display the local results. I also have other users where smart scopes are enabled and it doesn't take much longer to display local results (though there is some difference in time).

I think what slows down local result is *not* because some scopes are prioritized before others but maybe since more scopes means higher load on the processor. Also take into account that online scopes don't need much processing power **concerning each scope alone**, the computer just sends the query to online scopes and they send back the results, that may be the reason why online scopes display first. But together each scope contributes in putting load on the processor and therefore affecting the speed of the local scope. Actually displaying results itself can be considered as processor load.

...You can wait for a better answer though

Comment: That answer deals with Lens, though, and is therefore outdated. Regardless, I've also seen that scopes return results on a first-come first-served basis, but that simply cannot explain how disabling all online scopes let local results appear noticeably faster (e.g. the difference between .5 and 10 seconds); something else must be in play here, somehow.

Comment: outdated?! why? because it doesn't refer to data being uploaded to smart scopes' servers? anyways, it's content is correct.

Comment: would you tell me your computer's specs please?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant the answer you linked to was outdated, seeing as how the introduction of smart-scopes rendered lenses obsolete (at least to my understanding). But perhaps you're right; after disabling most scopes I still get long-queries sometimes (although certainly not always); could just be the way Dash does index/re-index.

Comment: yes I understand. As I was saying; it's only a matter of terms used but the content itself (of the linked question) is correct. ... yet my answer is based on assumptions. Sadly that's all I have to offer.